# Linker error in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

more then annoying linker-error here:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __std_terminate
```

I have no clue how to solve. Im using MSVC 2017 with a project build and using toolkit for MSVC2015.

Compiled fine and links until this very last error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the project type? (console?) Do you have anything non default under linker/input? (e.g. Ignore specific/all default libraries?)   You might also want to inspect, and perhaps paste the linker /VERBOSE output.

Answer (score 0):

If it compiled properly, it means that you have the header file or definition somewhere. What you need to do is add the library (which the symbol is from) in the linker properties of the project so that it can be found at the linking stage.